# Android: How to have a 1 - 2 - 1 list item formation in a GridView or RecyclerView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to achieve the following list item formation within a recycler or grid view:

```
 1
1 1
 1
1 1
 1
```

where `1` is a single view holder (list item). My list items all have the same width and height.

I've attempted to use a recyclerview with a grid layout manager as seen here:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));
```

But this will strictly display 2 columns.

I've tried using a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` also with my `recyclerView` as seen below:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

But this only stretches my list items to fit a 2 column list, similar to the `GridLayoutManager`.
I've also tried to change the width of 1 in 3 list views in my adapter, but the width of one view does not effect the position of another.

The current setup looks like this:

```
    adapterPre = new CategoryListAdapter(this, getContext(),GeneralUtils.isLoggedIn());
    RecyclerView premadeLists = view.findViewById(R.id.practise_recycler);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new CustomSpanSizeLookup());
    premadeLists.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    premadeLists.setHasFixedSize(false);
    premadeLists.setAdapter(adapterPre);
```

`CustomSpanSizeLookup`:

```
class CustomSpanSizeLookup extends GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `GridLayoutManager` with 2 spans and create a custom `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup`:

```java
class CustomSpanSizeLookup extends GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        /* one in three items will occupy the whole row, 
        * two in three items will take up half a row and can 
        * therefore be placed next to each other.
        */
        return position % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
```

You can set it on the `GridLayoutManager` with the method:

```java
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new CustomSpanSizeLookup());
```

Comment: Should I use `GridView` instead of `RecyclerView` for this?

Comment: No, you should use `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @KesWalker It should. Your cells have `match_parent` as width? The orientation of the `GridLayoutManager` is `VERTICAL`? Does it have a span size of 2?

Comment: okay, after making the cell width `match_parent`, some views are the width of the parent but some are half the width. This is not quite what I require. I need two views next to each other, not one view taking up the space of two views, sorry

Comment: Ah okay, I see now, if I change `position % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1` to `position % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1` it performs as expected, thankyou very much :)

Comment: @KesWalker no problem!